# ToArray() Method Clones All Instances as Last One

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, addition

I have an array and type like;

```
List<ContractListType> ContractsList = new List<ContractListType>();
ContractListType instance = new ContractListType();
```

I add 4 elements to my ContractsList 4 by

```
If a == 1
    instance.name = "A"
    ContractsList.Add(instance);
If b == 1
    instance.name = "B"
    ContractsList.Add(instance);
If c == 1
    instance.name = "C"
    ContractsList.Add(instance);
If d == 1
    instance.name = "D"
    ContractsList.Add(instance);
```

And finally I want to match my list with response.

```
response.GetContractListResponse.GetContractListResponseDTO.ContractListType = ContractsList.ToArray();
```

Although a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4; my response comes like

```
<name>D</name>
<name>D</name>
<name>D</name>
<name>D</name>
```

When I debug, before to response I can see all names in conractsList but when ToArray run, all names convert to "D", which is last one.

I Couldn't find a solution. Help me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With .NET/C#, you are not adding the object itself to the list but the reference to the object. Your code is adding the same reference 4 times and modifying the reference. You need to clone the object and change its property before adding it to the list to achieve your desired outcome.

Try this pattern.

```
If a == 1
    ContractsList.Add(new ContractListType{ name = "A" } );
```

MSDN offers a nice example of [implementing a Deep copy of your object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I see you, but don't know how to clone object and change its property before adding to list. Can you give an example please?

Comment: Create a new constructor that takes in a parameter of the same type and copy over the properties. Note that properties that are reference types (classes) will need their own clones too.

Comment: @Gyepesto there is no generic way to clone a object reliably in .NET. Usually you must provide a custom `.Clone()` method in the object or reconstruct it by hand at the point you need it like Babak showed (the `.Clone()` method will usually just contain the code you would have done for the "by hand" method and just return the resultant `new` object.).